# How to make Curved Text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text-decorations

I'm working on a Flutter project, and I'd like to add **Curved Text** to one of my widgets. I want the text to follow a curved  rather than being displayed in a straight line. I've been searching for a way to achieve this effect in Flutter, but I haven't found a straightforward solution.

[image]

I want to curved my text just like this in above showed image.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to create curved text in Flutter?

I'd appreciate any code examples or tutorials that can help me get started with this curved text feature in Flutter. Thank you!

Comment: first google hit is: https://medium.com/mews-devs/flutter-how-to-draw-text-along-an-arc-840d5501db69

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_arc_text
you can try this also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `curved_text: ^0.1.3`

```
import 'package:curved_text/curved_text.dart';



 Story(
        background: Colors.white,
        name: 'Curved text',
        builder: (_, k) {
          final curvature = k.slider(label: 'Curvature', initial: double.minPositive, min: -0.05, max: 0.05);

          final text = k.text(
            label: 'Text',
            initial: 'Hello, Flutter!',
          );
          const textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black);

          return CurvedText(
            curvature: curvature,
            text: text,
            textStyle: textStyle,
            targetRadius: 50,
          );
        },
      )
```

[image]

Comment: I would also like to suggest [these additional beautiful text kits](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit)

Comment: these is no such a feauture in that library